# How do I select a memory allocation implementation (heap_#.c file) in FreeRTOS?

Tags: freertos

FreeRTOS comes with 5 memory allocation implementations. How do I select the one I want to use? Do I include the appropriate "heap_#.c" file in my "main.c", is there some constant I need to set for this or do I just leave the "heap_#.c" I want to use in MemMang directory?

Comment: You can find the files at FreeRTOS\Source\portable\MemMang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either delete all "unwanted" `heap_#.c` files

or make sure you compile only the file you want to use and ignore all other files (depending on your build process).